# iOS : Where to start for AliPay integration?

Tags: ios, integration, payment-gateway, alipay

I've a requirement to integrate [AliPay](http://global.alipay.com/ospay/home.htm) payment gateway into my app, I've dived into google sea but unfortunately there's no fish for my need.

From somewhere, I found this link, https://globalprod.alipay.com/order/integrationGuide.htm, but there's no integration steps for the iOS app.

Does anyone implemented this before? Any documentation out there? Anything?

Comment: Greetings SO! I kindly request that this question should not be closed because this is completely a new question and will be really helpful if it'll answer well. `AliPay` is a payment gateway like `PayPal`, however there's still very less developer SDK documentation to integrate within the app. I believe that it'll be helpful to the wide range of developers who will/want to integrate `AliPay` into their application. Thanks! :)

Comment: Try this: http://download.alipay.com/public/api/base/WS_SECURE_PAY.zip

Comment: The latest sdks & demo here http://aopsdkdownload.cn-hangzhou.alipay-pub.aliyun-inc.com/demo/WS_MOBILE_PAY_SDK_BASE.zip?spm=0.0.0.0.HrX3a2&file=WS_MOBILE_PAY_SDK_BASE.zip

Comment: the official sdks download is from  https://doc.open.alipay.com/doc2/detail?treeId=59&articleId=103563&docType=1

Comment: Full Integration of Airplay : https://github.com/AlokPandey-IOS/AliPay-Integration--iOS

Answer (score 5):

Generally, there are two ways to do alipay.
1. Integrate the alipay SDK and use alipay App to do the job.
SDK download from: https://openhome.alipay.com/doc/docIndex.htm#goto=https://openhome.alipay.com/doc/viewKbDoc.htm?key=236698_261849&type=info  
2. Develop a wap web to pay on web, this is not our job...

Comment: Hey! Thanks mate! This link is useful. Here's the direct link for iOS SDK, https://i.alipayobjects.com/e/201310/ALPPassDemo.zip